# How to get all IdObjects in MongoDB using DropDownMenu in Flask

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask

I aim to use dropdownMenu of Bootstrap where each item in the menu gets an IdObject of my MongoDB.

The reason is I want to have those IdObjects in one list in order to get all the data that is stored in that collection. Therefore, here's my codes:

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    {% for row in rows %}
       <button class="dropdown-item" href="./get_object?_id={{row['_id']}}" type="button">{{row['_id']}}</button>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**Python**

```
@app.route("/get_object", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_object():
    cursor = object_collection.find({})
    for document in cursor:
        row = document['_id']
        return render_template("get_object.html", rows=row)
```

Somehow I didn't get what I want. I had some errors in python file and HTML. Is the way I am doing it okay?

```
  File "˜/application/app.py", line 52, in get_object
    return render_template("get_object.html", rows=row)

  File ˜/application/templates/get_object.html", line 18, in block "content"
    {% for row in rows %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want a list. Right now you have the `return` within the `for` loop. Instead, just append to a list and call the template with the whole list at once:

```
@app.route("/get_object", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_object():
    rows = []                               # define an empty list
    cursor = object_collection.find({},{ "_id": 1 })
    for document in cursor:
        rows.append(document['_id'])        # <- append to the list

    return render_template("get_object.html", rows=rows)  # Use the whole list in output
```

Note also that `.find({},{ _id: 1 })` in *projecting* **only** the `_id` field in results rather than the whole object. So this is useful when you only want the `_id` values so that unnecessary data is not sent over the network.

In your template, that's now just a *list of **values***, so there is no `_id` property. Just use the value:

```
<button class="dropdown-item" href="./get_object?_id={{row}}" type="button">{{row}}</button>
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot :) just missed quotes in `_id` so it would be `cursor = object_collection.find({},{" _id": 1 })`

Comment: @TimLuka Yes I missed the quotes. More time on JavaScript of late than python. Quotes on the key added.